# how do i apply condition through the table values?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, carousel, laravel-5.4

I am making a carousel which should display the info dynamically in it. And here i am trying to apply condition through which the result can be filtered but it doesn't seems to be working. Below is the code for it.(**what i really want to achieve through this is to appear the results in a carousel**). Any kind of help would be  immensely appreciated

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 75px">
            @if($tours->continent_id == 5)

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h3>Featured {{$tours->continent->name}}</h3>                
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <!-- Controls -->
          <div class="controls pull-right hidden-xs">
                        <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn-success" 
           href="#carousel-example"
                           data-slide="prev"></a><a class="right fa fa-
             chevron-
           right btn btn-success" href="#carousel-example"
                                                    data-slide="next"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-
          ride="carousel">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach($tours as $tour)
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="{{$tour->photo->file ? 
                  asset($tour->photo->file): asset('images/404.png')}}" 
            class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="price col-md-6">
                                                <h5>{{$tour->location}}</h5>
                                                <h5 class="price-text-
                   color">
                                                    {{$tour->service}}</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="rating hidden-sm 
                 col-md-
                        6">
                                                <i class="price-text-color 
           fa 
          fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="price-text-color 
         fa 
         fa-star"></i><i class="price-text-color fa fa-star">
                                            </i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="separator clear-left">
      <p class="btn-add"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a 
     href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">Add to cart</a>
    </p>

    <p class="btn-details"> <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a 
      href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="hidden-sm">More details</a>
      </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
       @endif
        </div>    
        </div>

Here is the controller part of the code. which is including all the fillable values in the form view. which later can be used to apply conditions on the form or return it's table values in the form 


    public function index()
    {$tours = Tour::all();
        return view('admin/tour/slider',compact('tours'));}
```

Error page [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djh8C.png)

Comment: What is the error here?

Comment: @ljubadr updated the post

Comment: `$tours->continent_id` is a collection of tours and not a single object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to do was to put if condition after the foreach statement for its values to be available for the loop at before that foreach loop i had to check for the existence of the values in the table like @if($tours). and it all worked nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to filter the tours and only interact with the ones that contain `continent_id` equals to `5`?

In that case, you should improve the query on database

```
$tours = Tour::where('continent_id', 5)->get();
```

Or filter the collection

```
$tours->filter(function ($tour) {

    return $tour->continent_id == 5;
}
```

In both cases, you won't be able to do `{{ $tours->continent->name }}` since you're working with a `Collection` of `Tour`, not with a `Tour` instance.

In order to print the title of the first tour you should do

```
$tours->first()->continent->name
```

Comment: what if i want to apply limt to all the values in continent_id one by one??

Comment: I don't know what do you mean @DaShInGSid

Comment: i mean to say is there i'm trying to get result of values associated with continent_id 5 and what i really need at that pages is values filtered by the continent_id's. And how can i do that if i limit the values i the controller by 5 or if i try to put the filter collection code in if condition it wont work there.

Comment: so basically at that page i am trying to filter  all the 7 continent related results

Comment: In that case iterate over continents and use laravel relations to iterate over continent's tour like `foreach ($continent->tours as $tour)`

Comment: and what about if statement??

Comment: You must not use conditional statements on templates to filter a foreach. It's better to filter the results before. You will loose future functionalities and flexibility. There should be zero or almost zero logic code in a view file

Comment: since i am new to laravel can you guide how can i filter it except view???